# Styling Forms Ruby on Rails 2 - Easy Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, forms

I am new to Rails so this is probably an easy question but can't find anything that seems to explain it well.

How do I style forms in rails to. When I try to use the default styling for input (for example) it styles my text field and create button the same. Is there a built in convention or do I have to add some sort of helper. If it is a helper can you you walk me through that as I have not done it before.

Here is my form:

```
<% form_for (Post.new) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :BattleCry %>
    <br/><i>Between 25 and 300 words</i><br/>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
  </p>
<% end %><hr/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most appropriate way would likely be just giving them different classes and styling them via usual css methods.

Eg.

```
<%= text_field( :title, :class => "something" ) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more of a CSS question.  You seem to be on the right track ruby-on-rails-wise.  Both text field and button are of type input in html, that's why your CSS style applied to both.